# Compare elements of two arraylist of different sizes and order in android

Tags: android, arraylist, compare

I am not getting the result true even when the first element of both arraylists are same.i want to check my checkbox when result matches.I have implemented it in my recyclerview I want to compare the elements of the arraylists but both are different in size.I found a solution online and implemented it like:.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        list1.add(data.get(i).getChannel_names());
                    }
                    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listNewsChannelsSelected.size(); i++) {
                        list2.add(listNewsChannelsSelected.get(i).getSelectedChannelsFromApi());
                    }

        private boolean equalLists(List<String> one, List<String> two) {
                if (one == null && two == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (one != null && two == null) {
                    return false;
                }


                one = new ArrayList<>(one);
                two = new ArrayList<>(two);

                Collections.sort(one);
                Collections.sort(two);
                return one.equals(two);
            }
    if (equalLists(list1,list2)) {
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
```

Comment: have u implemented both Comparer and Comparator, If yes, Post the details pls. If not u need to implement them

Comment: i have not @NirajSanghani. but why comparator when equlaLists method is already comparing.

Comment: I thingk then ur question is not clear regarding comparison

Comment: Comparer and Comparator is for Customization searching , sorting and list comparison ! You know that right?

Comment: but i am already comparing using one.equals(two). i want to know where is the fault as i am new to android.

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: Dude what do you want with that comparison i am not still clear, their are many examples, I am not sure what do u want, Its java, not android we are talking about.

Comment: because .equals checks if they are the same instance copies not the items in it

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and saw that there is nothing wrong in the code. (Bit modified to test in java). I am getting the result as **TRUE** so the code is correct.

Try to check your API data. It seems to be incorrect (not what you are expecting it to be). Try to generate logs (print api data in loop).

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list1.add(""+i);
    }
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list2.add(""+i);
    }

    if (equalLists(list1,list2)) {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }

}



private static boolean equalLists(List<String> one, List<String> two) {
    if (one == null && two == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (one != null && two == null) {
        return false;
    }


    one = new ArrayList<>(one);
    two = new ArrayList<>(two);

    Collections.sort(one);
    Collections.sort(two);
    return one.equals(two);
}
```